# TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 8, file "Code")

Tags: undefined, typeerror

So I am having trouble making this work. There was never a change to the form or the google sheet that the results went to, but it stopped working for some reason around last year this time. Can someone help me figure out what is going on? Side note: I am not a programmer. I inherited this form and everything that comes with it. I did not create the code or anything, so please any direction will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Try using `e.target.values` or `e.target.value`  instead of `e.values`.  That should fix your code

Comment: Would I need to change anything on my form or the .doc that it transfers the data to?

Comment: No, you would not